# Display Google Sheet IMPORTXML results horizontally

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to enter data in the first column of Google Sheet.
and the results in the second column should be displayed horizontally (using IMPORTXML)
But now it is displayed vertically.
This is my code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=fa-IR&q=("&A2&")","//CompleteSuggestion/suggestion[1]/@data")
```

The output now looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to be like this:

[image]

I tested the above piece of code in Google Sheets and the results are displayed vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Wrap `torow()`  to your existing importxml formula*

```
=torow(<importxml_formula>)
```